# which is the path to a file

Tags: jquery, file, path

Hi I have to read some files from an mobile app (html5, Phonegap).

How to point my app to the root directory of my device. With root I mean the dir that I see when I open "my files" app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `window.requestFileSystem`:

```
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

And:

```
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(window.appRootDirName, {
        create : true,
        exclusive : false
    }, dirReady, fail);
```

This Gist should be helpful for you: https://gist.github.com/2894564